# Show Notice: "Undefined variable: arr on line 40" when data table is empty

Tags: php

I made a public function View() under a class Delivary(). But in line 40 I return $arr. Now it show Undefined variable: arr when my data table is empty.
**Notice: Undefined variable: arr in C:\xampp\htdocs\online shop\dataAccessLayer\dalDelivary.php on line 40**

My code is:

```
class Delivary {

public $place;
public $address;
public $amount;
public $date;
public $payment;
public $walletnumber;
public $user_id;

public function DB()
{
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","project");
    return $connection;
}

public function Insert()
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO delivery (place, address, amount, `date`,payment, walletnumber, user_id) VALUES 
    ('$this->place', '$this->address', '$this->amount', '$this->date', '$this->payment', '$this->walletnumber', '$this->user_id');";
    if(mysqli_query($this->DB(), $sql))
    {
        return true;
    }
        return false;
}

public function View()
{
    $sql = "SELECT delivery.delivery_id, service.area, delivery.address, delivery.amount, delivery.date, delivery.payment, delivery.walletnumber, delivery.user_id FROM delivery, service WHERE service.service_id = delivery.place";
    $result = mysqli_query($this->DB(),$sql);
    while($d = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
        {
            $arr[] = $d; 
        }
        return $arr; //line 40
}
public function Delete()
    {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM delivery WHERE delivery_id = '".$this->delivery_id."'";
        if(mysqli_query($this->DB(), $sql))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }}
```

Comment: declare $arr after the start of function like $arr = [];

Comment: What if `mysqli_fetch_row` don't get any data. What `$arr` will return;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
public function View()
{
    $sql = "SELECT delivery.delivery_id, service.area, delivery.address, delivery.amount, delivery.date, delivery.payment, delivery.walletnumber, delivery.user_id FROM delivery, service WHERE service.service_id = delivery.place";
    $result = mysqli_query($this->DB(),$sql);
    while($d = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
        {
            $arr[] = $d; 
        }
        return $arr; //line 40
}
```

TO

```
    public function View()
    {
        $arr = [];
        //Please correct the following SQL statement as per your requirement.
        $sql = "SELECT delivery.delivery_id, service.area, delivery.address, delivery.amount, delivery.date, delivery.payment, delivery.walletnumber, delivery.user_id FROM delivery, service WHERE service.service_id = delivery.place";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->DB(),$sql);
        while($d = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
            {
                $arr[] = $d; 
            }
        return $arr; //line 40
    }
```

And the error should go. Since you are directly pushing to $arr in the while loop, PHP is not able to find  $arr in case where your query returns 0 records. Since your query returns 0 records, it doesnt execute the code in `while loop` and hence PHP is not aware of $arr.

Comment: After Use your code my database don't show anything

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing `$arr` like an array before it's been defined as one. To eliminate this notice (Which is more a warning than an error), simply define the array before you use it:

```
$arr = [];
while($d = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
     $arr[] = $d; 
}
return $arr; //line 40
```

Make sure you're checking for errors from the return of the `mysqli_query` function:

```
$conn = $this->DB();
$sql = "SELECT delivery.delivery_id, service.area, delivery.address, delivery.amount, delivery.date, delivery.payment, delivery.walletnumber, delivery.user_id FROM delivery, service WHERE service.service_id = delivery.place";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if ( !$result ) {
    echo "There was an error executing this query: ", mysqli_error($conn);
    exit;
}
$arr = [];
while($d = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
    $arr[] = $d; 
}
return $arr;
```

Comment: After Use your code my database don't show anything

Comment: Pet peeve: Delivary is spelled wrong. It should be Delivery. Check my updated answer for how to check for mysql errors.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now my problem is solved. just change sql query "select * from delivery"; and add $arr = [];

Comment: What do you mean just change sql query?

Comment: Change $sql = "SELECT delivery.delivery_id, service.area, delivery.address, delivery.amount, delivery.date, delivery.payment, delivery.walletnumber, delivery.user_id FROM delivery, service WHERE service.service_id = delivery.place"; to $sql = "SELECT * from delivery";

Comment: It's not my job to change your SQL query. You posted an issue about a NOTICE error from your $arr not being defined. That issue has been solved. Just because you're getting a SQL error, which appears to be another issue entirely, doesn't negate that this answer has solved your question. Changing the sql statement offers absolutely nothing that would help future readers.

Comment: Here is also a array problem. your solve was also right. need to add $arr = []; which i was also mention please check.